# How do I create a modal for an image that is inside a horizontal gallery?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, image-gallery

I'm creating a portfolio and have a horizontally scrolling gallery with screenshots of personal projects of mine. Upon clicking one of the screenshot images, I want a modal to pop-up with relevant case study material.

Here is my attempt at the first projects case-study modal.

No modal is appearing and it just jumps to the top of the page. Can anyone provide any help on how to accomplish this?

First post here...please be gentle!

HTML

```
    <!-- Work Section -->
<section id="work" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="gallery horizontal-gallery">
                <a href="#" id="work-modals">
                    <img id="project-src" src="Images/todolist.png">
                </a>
                <img src="Images/todolist.png">
                <img src="Images/todolist.png">
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Work Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ToDoList</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="" id="imagepreview">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
$("#work-modals").on("click", function() {
    $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#project-src').attr('src'));
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nnnsd71c/)**

Comment: I'm with @isherwood. Can you please put code into jsfiddle, at least?

Comment: Seems to work fine judging by the demo I put in your question. Notice that I've changed your ID to a class, and made a small change to your src jQuery statement. Still, it worked as you had it.

Comment: You'll want to look in the browser console for errors and report them. Are you sure the modal isn't showing up, just down the page?

Comment: OK, this is very weird. It works in the fiddle, but literally just jumps to the top of my page with no modal in site. Could it have something to do with snap-scroll i have in place for that section?

Comment: I literally asked for two things in my previous comment. Please provide them. :)

Comment: Its throwing 404 errors that it cannot find my bootstrap js link in my html. Console errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://127.0.0.1:51340/js/bootstrap.min.js   Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js:6

Answer (score 0):

try preventing default browser action so window location isn't changed.
part 1:

```
$("#work-modals").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#project-src').attr('src'));
  $('#modal1').modal('show');
});
```